# How do I copy all strings that match a certain pattern in my email

Tags: gmail

I've got a chain of emails and I managed to open them as a different window. Now I need to go through and copy all numbers that start with the numbers 123.  Any ideas?

EXAMPLE,

1234848449
2311110922
1239474942
1239585085
2837918273
1234947404
2893719222

I need to copy all numbers that start with 123 and past them into a different document. Or generate a document with all the numbers

I've tried looking for extensions like find+ or chrome regex but they only copy all iterations of 123 and not the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use regex you can simply search for numbers starting with 123 repeating 9 times in total, for example:

```
123[0-9]{7}
```

This will obtain:

```
pos     group
0-10    1234848449
22-32   1239474942
33-43   1239585085
55-65   1234947404
```

If you need to capture the group, just encase it witn parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned find+.

I don't know the extension but if it does a regex then this line `123[0-9]{0,}` might do the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
\b123\d+\b
```

- `\b` word boundary, this ensures the word you're matching starts with
  your regex expression
- `123` word must start with sequence 123
- `d+`  1 or more digits
- `\b` word boundary, marks the end of word you're
  matching.